# Samsung Store Apps Installer Package name

Tags: android, google-play, samsung-galaxy, package-name, galaxy-apps

As Google and Amazon return `com.android.vending` and `com.amazon.venezia`respectively for

```
val pm = packageManager
val installer = pm.getInstallerPackageName(packageName)
```

What will be the check to find whether the app is installed from a Samsung store?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package name for the Samsung Galaxy Apps Store is `com.sec.android.app.samsungapps`.